# Combining rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas DataFrame shown below consisting of three columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, "User1", "Hello."], [1, "User1", "How are you?"], [1, "User2", "I'm fine."], [2, "User1", "Nice to meet you."], [2, "User2", "Hello."], [2, "User2", "I'm happy."], [2, "User2", "Goodbye."], [3, "User2", "Hello."]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Conversation', 'User', 'Text'])
```

```
   Conversation   User              Text
0             1  User1             Hello.
1             1  User1      How are you?
2             1  User2         I'm fine.
3             2  User1  Nice to meet you.
4             2  User2             Hello.
5             2  User2         I'm happy.
6             2  User2           Goodbye.
7             3  User2             Hello.
```

I would like to merge the Text of groups of consecutive Users, but not over conversation boundaries. If in a Conversation a User has several consecutive rows, I would like to merge these rows into one row by combining the Text with whitespace. When a new Conversation starts, it should not be combined. For the example, the result should look as follows:

```
   Conversation   User              Text
0             1  User1             Hello. How are you?
2             1  User2         I'm fine.
3             2  User1  Nice to meet you.
4             2  User2             Hello. I'm happy. Goodbye.
7             3  User2             Hello.
```

How can this be achieved in an efficient way (I have a big DataFrame)?

Comment: Very similar question: [Conditionally merge consecutive rows of a pandas dataframe](/q/63853639/4518341)

Comment: What have you already tried? If you know how to use `.groupby` and `.agg` already, then the only thing you'd be missing would be grouping consecutive `User`s, and there's an existing question about basically that: [How to groupby consecutive values in pandas DataFrame](/q/40802800/4518341). Does that answer your question?

Comment: BTW, please read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: That might be a bad example since there are no non-consecutive `User`s within each `Conversation`.

Comment: is `df.groupby(['Conversation','User'])['Text'].agg(' '.join).reset_index()` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the example to include the conditions that were specified.  One way to do this is to introduce a temporary boundary column, and then group by the boundary, conversation and user.  If so desired the boundary column can be removed.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [1, "User1", "Hello."], 
    [1, "User2", "How are you?"], 
    [1, "User1", "I'm fine."], 
    [2, "User1", "Nice to meet you."], 
    [2, "User2", "Hello."], 
    [2, "User2", "I'm happy."], 
    [2, "User2", "Goodbye."], 
    [1, "User1", "Bye now."]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Conversation', 'User', 'Text'])


df['Boundary'] = ((df['Conversation'].astype(str) + df['User']) != (df['Conversation'].astype(str) + df['User']).shift()).cumsum()
print(df.groupby(['Boundary','Conversation', 'User'], as_index=False, sort=True).agg(' '.join).drop(columns=['Boundary']))
```

Output:

```
   Conversation   User                        Text
0             1  User1                      Hello.
1             1  User2                How are you?
2             1  User1                   I'm fine.
3             2  User1           Nice to meet you.
4             2  User2  Hello. I'm happy. Goodbye.
5             1  User1                    Bye now.
```